# setAttribute() in a multi dimensional array

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to figure out is how to give another class to certain div's in a two-dimensional array that has a value of "3" . This is what I tried at first.

- numRows are the amount rows in the array.
- numSeatsPerRow are the number of array items in every "numRows".
- r and t are the positions in the two-dimensional array.

  ```
  for(var r = 0; r<numRows; r++){
      for(var t = 0; t<numSeatsPerRow; t++){

          if(myArray[r][t] === 3){

              document.getElementsByTagName("div")[r][t].setAttribute("class", "busySpot");

          }
      }
  }
  ```

I soon understood that this wouldn't work. I tried to make a formula which could calculate every position as an ordinary array but couldn't make it work. Is there any other way to solve my problem?

In the code below I create a two-dimensional array based on two different inputs

```
    var myArray = new Array(numRows);
    for(var i = 0; i <numRows; i++){
        myArray[i] = new Array(numSeatsPerRow);
    }
```

In the next piece of code I give all array items the value 1 and then draw a green box for every item.

```
for(var h = 0; h<numRows; h++){
        document.body.appendChild(//efter varje rad sker ett <br> i utskriften
        document.createElement("br"));
        document.body.appendChild(
        document.createElement("br"));
        for(var g = 0; g<numSeatsPerRow; g++){              
            myArray[h][g] = 1
                    var vSpot = document.createElement("div");
                    vSpot.className = "vacantSpot";
                    document.body.appendChild(vSpot);


        }
    }
```

What I'm trying to do in the top code is give the random boxes that I talked about another class.

this is how i came up with the random coordinates:

```
for(var v = 0; v < 15; v++){
    var test = true;
    while(test){
        var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * numSeatsPerRow) + 0 );
        var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * numRows) + 0);
        if(myArray[x][y] === 1) {
            myArray[x][y] = 3;
            test = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Well you need to give us an array of divs on how you structured it... without it it is hard to understand to which elements you want the property set.

Comment: well i have added a bunch of content sorry if it got messy:(

Comment: A table is the best way to visualize a multidimensional array.

Comment: When storing the value of a specific seat (1 or 3) to the `myArray[x][y]` store it as an array and store the dive element as well. Like this: `myArray[x][y] = [ 1, vSpot];`. That way when you later access it via random numbers you already have the cooresponding Div as a 2nd parameter... `myArray[x][y][0] = 3; myArray[x][y][1].classList.add('name');`